# "AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute '__name__' " while using '.after_idle'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, attributeerror

I am using `.after_idle` to make sure my tkinter program does not crash when in a loop.

But every time I press the `start`(tkinter.Button()) button, this happens:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ************************************************************, line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File ************************************************************, line 78, in panel
    win.after_idle(win, panel)
  File ************************************************************, line 820, in after_idle
    return self.after('idle', func, *args)
  File ************************************************************, line 810, in after
    callit.__name__ = func.__name__
  File ************************************************************, line 2345, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

How can I fix this? What's causing it? To help with answering:

here's my code:

```
import tkinter
import os
import time
#control rod percentages
cr1 = 100

p = '%'

#grid pieces
c1 = 'CTRL ROD 01 '
ins = ' INSERTED'

grid1 = ' _________________________ '
grid2 = '|'
grid3 = '|_________________________|'
def panel():
    print(grid1)
    print(grid3)
    win.after_idle(panel)
    os.system('cls')

win = tkinter.Tk(className=' N.M.S. ')
w = tkinter.Button(win, activeforeground="black", activebackground="red", bg="grey", fg="black", command=panel, text="START", height=1, width=10)
w.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

-----------------------------------------------------[NOTE]--------------------------------------------------------------------

This code is not complete. Its in construction and testing phase. I just ran into the problem and I am really stumped by it.

PS: I am using python 3.8.0. Does this change anything?

Comment: `win.after_idle(win, panel)` should be `win.after_idle(panel)` as the first argument to `after_idle(...)` should be a callback.  Also better to remove the last line `panel()` inside `panel()` as it may cause recursive issue.

Comment: @acw1668 New problem: removing ```panel()``` last line worked, but once the program is started: it can't be stopped. any fix?

Comment: not even ctrl + c stopes it.

Comment: I don't have the issue in my Windows 10 running Python 3.8.2 if the mentioned changes are applied to your posted code.

Comment: @ acw1668 Creating the changes as requested. However, I am using Python 3.8.0. Does this change anything?

Comment: I don't think it is the issue of Python version if you use your posted code to test.  It may be other part of your code if your posted code is only part of your program.

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]. I suspect that your problem is reproducible whether you have 16 print statements and strings and "grid pieces" or just 1.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have made the changes as requested.

Comment: @acw1668 This is a little late, but My computer is very old and MIGHT be the source of my problem. Oops. Still, if you can find a solution... it would be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `win.after_idle(...)` to `win.after(500, panel)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Unfortunately, this results in the error above.